# Iteration to update 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

Hi so essentially I have the basic text file:

```
3
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
```

And I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional array that contains the values as integers.
My code so far is:

```
import numpy as np
f = open('perc.txt', 'r')
n = f.readline()
j = 0
dim = int(n.rstrip(' \n'))
mat = np.zeros((dim, dim))
for i in range(dim):
    n = f.readline()
    line = n.rstrip(' \n')
    line = line.split()
    line = map(int,line)
    while j < dim: 
        mat[i][j] = line[j]
        j += 1
```

But when I run the code, the result is:

```
1 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

yet line is currently the array[(1, 1, 1)] so clearly that part of the iteration is working correctly.  How can I get the matrix to update values properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
with open(...) as outfile:
    #outfile.write()
    #outfile.read()
    #outfile.readlines()
    #etc
```

to have the file automatically close for you. It looks better and you don't have to remember to close the file.

I just read the whole thing in and split the string into a list. Then I used the indices to create the array.

`arr = np.array([lines[1:])` creates a flat array of each element in `lines` starting at the 2nd element, so I resized it using the `dim x dim` you provided with the `resize` function.

```
import numpy as np

lines = []

with open('perc.txt', 'r') as outfile:
    lines = outfile.read().split()

>>> print lines
>>> ['3', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1']

arr = np.array([lines[1:]])

dim = int(lines[0])

arr.resize(dim, dim)

>>> print arr
>>> [['1' '0' '1']
     ['0' '1' '0']
     ['1' '1' '1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `j` to zero before the `while` loop.